# Add big piece of HTML to the html-panel

Tags: html, gwt

I am new to GWT and I need to add a big piece of html code (contains a lot of included divs with id and classes) to the html-panel widget in my java file.
I have tried to add like this:

```
HTML html = new HTML("<div class=\"class1\">This is a class1.");
HTML html2 = new HTML("And it ends here</p>");
RootPanel.get().add(html);
RootPanel.get().add(html2);
```

But I have a problem with included divs. Is there any simpler way to this big piece of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, sir, are looking for UiBinder:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder

UiBinder is great when you are doing a lot in plain HTML.

However, UiBinder offers a lot once you get in deep so be careful. I recommend looking into CssResource and how it releates to UiBinder so you can share some Css or just embed Css in each UiBinder file. (Note programatic access to Css within UiBinder files)

Also not other features such as importing other custom UiBinder/Widgets with namespaces such as the built in (< g:Button> -> < mynamespace:MyCustomWidget>)

But you are probably just looking for laying everything out in UiBinder and defining the @UiField's in the java file

Hope this helps!

-Ashton

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is static, you must use UiBinder.

If your HTML is generated dynamically, you can use com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML.

Your code is not working because you must give to the HTML constructor a valid html string.

I suggest you to read this guide:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml#Prefer_Plain_Text.